# Using list-index base in hibernate 4

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-4.x

Well, I'm trying to use list-index tag in XML map like this:

```
        <list-index column="order" base="0"/>
```

But sometimes i need start from 1. If i use base="0" and start from 1 in my Java Bean, the hibernate forces the order=1, and i want to avoid this.

Look:

```
myBean.setOrder(1);//hibernate change to '0'
```

If i change my list-index to base='1' when i need start with '0' the hibernate set '1'. How can i solve this ?